# How to sort date format d/m/y on bootstrap datatables plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, date, datatable

I am using [this](https://github.com/Comanche/datatables-responsive) bootstrap data-tables responsive plugin. Everything is fine, but this plugin can't sort the column with date (dd/mm/YYYY) format. The plugin only can sort with YYYY/mm/dd format.
So, how can I sort the dd/mm/YYYY date format with this plugin?

By the way, I am found the [plugin code](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-euro) from the datatables.net that allow to sort the dd/mm/YYYY format.

Can someone help me to combine (may be) the original plugin and the add on code above?
Thanks...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in td tag add a hidden span tag with date in format YYYY/mm/dd.

**HTML:**

```
<td><span class="hidden">YYYY/mm/dd</span>dd/mm/YYYY</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{display:none}
```